# Why is my picture in html not popping up on my browser

Tags: html

I'm trying to put this image I have saved in this location:

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\HTML docs\Lab 02\images

to put on my html code here:

```
<body>
<img src="C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/HTML docs/Lab 02/images/logo.gif" alt="Sintok Pizza Order Form Logo" width="300" height="268">
</body>
```

And, yes, as you can see on the code, the image is named logo.gif

But the image doesn't show up on my browser, what am I missing here? Please point out my errors, thanks!

Comment: Are you running this html file locally? Or have you uploaded this file to a server?

Comment: locally. Have not uploaded this on a web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepend the path with `file:///`

```
file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/HTML docs/Lab 02/images/logo.gif
```

Better way is to use relative paths. Assuming your html-file is in

```
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/HTML docs/Lab 02/
```

You should use

```
images/logo.gif
```

as your path.

Answer (score 1):

us file path like

```
file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/HTML docs/Lab 02/images/logo.gif
```

In these cases `open file with any browser` and the `copy the path used by browser` is a shortcut to test the path

Comment: This question has been answered, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You have been using the local computer path. Which is wrong. You need to use the web path.

See This : `C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/HTML docs/Lab 02/images/logo.gif`

This is pointing to your C: drive which is only accessible from your computer not others. you need to put up the image path as something like

```
./images/logo.gif
```